# Handlebars js error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js

I have a bootstrap template with dynamic sidebar and their repective pages.

Am using handlebarjs on the sidebar as well as on the pages.

Once when I click on the tabs in the sidebar I want to display its respective pages.

How to do this using Handlebars js.

Sidebar html:

```
<script id="sin" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
<div class = "tabs-left light-tab">
<ul  class="nav nav-tabs medium-icon" id="nav_list">
<li class="active"> 
{{#each Left}}
<a href="#" data-tab-id="s1">
<span class="icon icon-untitled"></span> {{this}} </a>
{{/each}}
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</script>
```

One of the page content html:

```
<script id="b_i" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#BI}}
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="span6">
<div class="control-group">
<label>{{this.TD}}</label>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
{{/BI}}
```

Json for sidebar is dynamic like below:

```
var source   = $("#sin").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);


var data = {
    "Left": [
    "BI",
    "Sim",
    "BC",
    "DP",
    "asdf"

]
};
$("p").append(template(data));
```

Json for page content:

```
var sources   = $("#b_i").html();
var templates = Handlebars.compile(sources);

var fields = {
"BUSINESSIDENTIFICATION": [
{
   "TD": "hi",
    }
]
};
```

Comment: show us your code please !

Comment: I have added the code in my question

Answer (score 0):

The following code of yours has a comma after the value "hi". Remove that comma.

Also for the content page you need to append the template with the values coming from fields variable